# Who sets the BROWSER environment variable in macOS?

Tags: terminal, environment-variables

I noticed I have `BROWSER` set to `open` in my environment variables, but I can't figure out where it gets set by the system.

When I run `env` I get this output:

```
USER=xxx
PATH=xxx
LOGNAME=xxx
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=xxx
HOME=xxx
SHELL=xxx
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=xxxx
TMPDIR=xxx
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=xxx
XPC_FLAGS=xxx
BROWSER=open
EDITOR=nano
[...]
```

It doesn't seem like something on my user configuration, is it standard to have `BROWSER=open` in macOS (10.15.3)? Where can I find the configuration file that sets it?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: @nohillside both bash and zsh have the same environment variable set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BROWSER` is not set by default on macOS. Where exactly it is set depends on the shell you are using and its specific configuration:

- **bash**: `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`
- **zsh**: `/etc/zshenv`, `/etc/zprofile`, `/etc/zshrc`, `/etc/zlogin`, `~/.zshenv`, `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.zlogin`

Besides the configuration files itself the variable may also get set in a script sourced from one of them.

Comment: And: LaunchDaemons/LaunchAgents! ;-) or a combination of plist and LaunchAgent  (e.g. Hannes Schmidt's *Environment Variables*)

Comment: @klanomath How can Launch{Agent,Daemon}s influence the environment variables you see in a shell?

Comment: `/bin/launchctl setenv FOO BAR` properly packed in a Launch{Agent|Daemon} (and loaded, of course)

Comment: @klanomath You're sure this still works in recent versions? We have several questions about setting environment variables during launch/startup, the answer typically are outdated or indicate it can't be done.

Comment: Recently (27 mins ago) tested in a 10.15.3 VM ;-)

Comment: @klanomath You rock!

Comment: Should I add the Launch{Agent|Daemon} part to your answer or do you want to do this yourself (or not at all)?

Comment: @klanomath Please go ahead!

Answer (score 3):

To answer myself, `BROWSER`, `EDITOR`, `VISUAL` and `PAGER` are all set by `~/.zprofile`.

They seem to be added by the Prezto ZSH configuration framework.